# How to set an action to a part of UILabel?

Tags: swift, storyboard, uilabel

I'd like to set an action to a "part" of UILabel not the all of UIlabel, like the "term of service" of attached picture. I am using storyboard. Now, I'm thinking to cover the UIButton over the part of UILabel. However, it is troublesome to adjust the part of label with the button at any layout(iPhone 5, 6 and 6 plus) by autolayout. If you know better way, please tell me. Thank you for your kindness.

[image]

Comment: You can try the TTTAttributedLabel library which supports hyperlinks: https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel (there are many other similar ones)

Comment: You could also use a `UIButton` - not sure what makes it hard to layout

Comment: Dear Aaron
Thank you! In terms of UIButton, should I prepare UIlabel and UIButton, the label  "By continuing you indicate that you have read and agree to the" and the button "Terms of Service"?

Comment: I guess it's a little bit of a pain, but you can get the rect for a specific line of text [by using `NSTextContainer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20633388/1445366

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved by using TTTAttributedLabel! 
https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using a `UITextView` with an `NSAttributedString`. Get the range of the text you are looking for, and then add the button as a subview to the view.

```
NSRange termsOfServiceRange = [self.termsOfUseTextView.text rangeOfString:@"Terms of Service"];
self.termsOfUseTextView.selectedRange = termsOfServiceRange;
UITextRange *termsOfServiceTextRange = [self.termsOfUseTextView selectedTextRange];
CGRect termsOfServiceFrame = [self.termsOfUseTextView firstRectForRange:termsOfServiceTextRange];
CGRect convertedFrame = [self.view convertRect:termsOfServiceFrame fromView:self.termsOfUseTextView];

UIButton *termsOfServiceButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:convertedFrame];
[termsOfServiceButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[termsOfServiceButton addTarget:self action:@selector(termsOfServiceButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:termsOfServiceButton];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:termsOfServiceButton];
```

Comment: That won't make the link change colors when you tap on it. Bad UX.